# How to connect two lists and produce customized reports

Tags: list, custom-list, content-query-web-part, filter

I have two lists. The first list, 'Suppliers', is a list of suppliers with the various contact information. The second is 'Ratings' this contains a lookup of the supplier name and various number fields with a percentage in them. The goal is to create an list of Ratings that is a pretty simple content query web part. I need to use the cqwp because there will be new ratings added and I only want the most recent for each supplier.

The part I am having issue with is that I want to be able to click the title in the webpart of the Ratings list and get a fully branded webpage that pulls in that supplier's information from both lists. I have tried all of my normal avenues and am running out of ideas of how to accomplish this without a custom farm solution. Is there a way to edit the list's display form.

Many Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What version of SP are you on?

Comment: 2010 Enterprise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid creating custom farm solution by implementing pure html+javascript solution.
Then you can add javascript+html on a page by using CEWP.

There is a special library called [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) which can help to get data from SharePoint and you can use jQuery for example to build your ratings. You can even build graphical elements using many popular jQuery plugins.

Personally, I think it is the only approach which is fluent enough and doesn't require you to build farm solutions.

And it is modern too paying attention to cloud solutions.

Comment: I was looking at that yesterday but haven't used it before. I see many version issues on the site. Do you know if it works with jquery-1.10.2?

Comment: We used it for SharePoint 2010 solutions. It is quite stable and there are many examples of using it. As for the jQuery version, you should consider using compatible version to be 100% sure but nothing prevents you from give it a try. I don't have information about latest jQuery version compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

You can customise the XSL of the CQWP so that when you click on an item it takes you to a custom page.  Further you could add a parameter to that call to define which supplier you want displayed on the page and then filter web parts on the custom page using the parameter.

There are posts on basic XSL and also how to use it with CQWP on http://paylord.wordpress.com

Comment: I know the basics of the CQWP and XSL, and that was the direction I was trying to take. What I would like to do is pass the parameter to a new page and have another CQWP receive it. That connection is what I am trying to figure out how to do. Would you have any examples on how to do that?

Comment: In your CQWP filter using [PageQueryString: Column Name].